# ASPdotnetstorefront dbo.SecurityLog row deleting

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I've acquired the maintenance task for an aspdotnetstorefront website that appears to have not had the maintenance scripts from the admin panel run for several years.

I've since ran each, but this has only freed up roughly 50MB.  I have a table inside of the database (dbo.SecurityLog) that has rows from several years ago (2012).  I assume that these rows display by going to Maintenance > Security, but because of the sheer size of the table, the application times out (Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.)

Would deleting older rows from 2012 be safe to do or would this cause possible issues with the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this based off the following link:

[Is my SQL Server Express 2008 R2 database about to hit the size limit and crash my website?](http://forums.vortx.com/?qa=350/server-express-2008-database-about-size-limit-crash-website)

The post contributors discuss several issues with the aspdotnetstorefront in regards to database size growing, along with methods to clear rows, one of which is the SecurityLog table.  I cleared this table up to a specified date, and all is well, freeing up 300MB+